# Post to same page but clear textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm posting text from a form to an area on the same page but the text area that has the content still retains the content after submit.

*Submit button*

```
<input type="button" class="button_add_task button menu_button" value="Add Task" style="width:40%;float:left;"  onclick="showInput();">
```

*Textarea*

```
<textarea id="apple3_input" name="apple3" style="width: 270px;height: 100px;font-size:16px;margin-bottom:5px;border:1px solid #000000;"></textarea><br>
```

*Where I have content showing up on same page*

```
<p style="font-size:12px"><b><span id="apple3"></span></b></p>
```

If I remove

```
onclick="showInput();"
```

Then the content does not show up on the page where I want it, so that's not a viable option.

Any thoughts?

Comment: and `showInput` do what? show us your javascript.

Comment: My jsFiddle is at jsfiddle.net/chrispopp8/tk7kugvo/10 (Note: for some reason at jsFiddle the ability to see text from the form on the task element is NOT WORKING. It is working fine in my environment at work with local files but on our outside server. )

Answer (score 1):

You can either extend to showInput() method adding this part:

```
document.getElementById('apple3_input').value = '';
```

What do you mean by posting on the same page? It is an Ajax Request, because from my understanding, I guess that that what showInput() by filling up the 



 with content.

We need more to see where or what is the problem.
Also, if the content of the **textarea** it is an auto complete by the browser, you can use in your form tag the following parameters:

```
<form ... autocomplete="off">
```

Be more specific.

Comment: I'm using jsPlumb and am putting titles into elements from a form on the same page so the user can build a flowchart easily.

My jsFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/chrispopp8/tk7kugvo/10

(Note: for some reason at jsFiddle the ability to see text from the form on the task element is NOT WORKING. It is working fine in my environment at work with local files but on our outside server. )

Comment: I added function: $('#apple3_input').val(''); / ('#apple1_input').val('');
 in the bottom of the showInput function. But before all this, resolve all your issues in the script (include jsPlumb and jQuery correctly, before your script... Ohhh.. and add the limitText function or remove it from your textarea..